# Deploying an ASP.NET MVC project with IoC-managed dependencies

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, web-deployment

We've recently adapted the following common structure for most of our internal solutions:

```
SolutionRoot
    Interfaces
    Models
    Services
    Repositories
    Web
```

where `Services`, `Repositories` and `Web` only have direct references to `Interfaces` and `Models` projects. All dependencies are managed via an IoC container (we've created a custom wrapper in our internal framework). Of course, `Services` and `Repositories` might have their own sets of external dependencies.

Now, when we deploy the `Web` MVC project, we obviously need to have all the necessary DLLs in the **bin** folder. Because there're no direct dependencies from the `Web` project to specific implementations, I've ended up writing a simple post-build script for the `Services` and the `Repositories` projects, which copy all the relevant DLLs to the **bin** folder of the `Web` (or any other consuming project). I then need to include the relevant DLLs in the project and mark them as Content.

Obviously, this isn't the most comfortable way to manage dependencies on deployment.

What I'd like to know is whether there's a better way to solve this issue.

*Note*: At this point, we don't have a CI server, and none is planned in the immediate future.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the following assumptions are true :

- the convention in your team is to never use implementations inside Services and Repositories directly from Web
- this convention is well understood and followed
- you don't need to reference different implementations for different deployments

then go for the easy way and just reference those projects in the Web project.

Otherwise, you're stuck with post build events.